# How to have a line in Microsoft Word with multiple DIFFERENTLY formatted sections of text using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to use a macro to expedite some LabVIEW code that needs to write a report automatically for a client, it needs to be formatted a certain way, though.  The issue I'm having is when I execute the code below with one format, and then execute it again using a different format, it reformats the previous line written, as well.  I've been able to solve this using a .TypeParagraph, but I don't always want a carriage return after a line of text is written to the document.  I've tried searching for how to break Word's selection, but have so far been unsuccessful.

Here's the code I'm executing:

```
Sub TextLineCreate(Text As String, Optional Style As String = "Title", Optional Bold As Boolean = True, Optional Italics As Boolean = False, Optional Underline As Boolean = False, Optional FontSize As Long = 16, Optional Alignment As String = "Center", Optional LineReturn As Long = 1)
'
' TextLineCreate Macro
' Creates a Formatted String with Text 'String'
'
Dim PreviousStyle As Style
Dim I As Long

Set PreviousStyle = Selection.Style ' Saves previous style configuration.

'Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory    ' Moves to the end of the document.

With Selection
    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(Style)

    Select Case (Alignment)
        Case ("Center"):
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        Case ("Left"):
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        Case ("Right"):
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
        Case Else
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    End Select

    If (Underline) Then
        .Font.UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    Else
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
    End If

    .Font.Bold = Bold               ' Sets the boldness

    If (Italics) Then
        .Font.Italic = True
    Else
        .Font.Italic = False
    End If
    ' Sets the Italicization

    .Font.Size = FontSize           ' Sets the font size.

    .TypeText Text:=Text

    .TypeParagraph

    If Bold Then .Font.Bold = False ' Restores previous bold setting
    .Style = PreviousStyle          ' Restores previous style configuration.

    For I = 1 To LineReturn
        .TypeParagraph                  ' Adds any desired white space
    Next I

End With

End Sub
```

Here is a link to a picture of the problem: https://imgur.com/a/CEk4Q

Here is a link to a picture of the problem with the return characters visualized: https://imgur.com/a/NG0M8

[UPDATE] Okay, I've continued working on this, and I have narrowed down the problem

All I need to do, is to be able to produce one line of text that has a bold and underlined section title, and a normal text description after.  I have tried a couple different methods and even consulted my macro book for excel that has 1 chapter on automating excel. Here is the code that I have right now, along with pictures of what is happening upon execution.

```
Sub TextLineCreate(Text As String, _
               Optional Style As String = "Normal", _
               Optional Bold As Boolean = True, _
               Optional Italics As Boolean, _
               Optional Underline As Boolean, _
               Optional FontSize As Long = 16, _
               Optional Alignment As String, _
               Optional LineReturn As Long)

' TextLineCreate Macro
' Creates a Formatted String with Text 'String'

Dim Rng As Range
Dim TextRng As Range
Dim Align As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim CharCount As Long
Dim StartIndex As Long
Dim EndIndex As Long

Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Rng

    .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(Style)
    .Text = Text

    CharCount = ActiveDocument.Characters.Count                 ' Determines how many characters are on the sheet
    StartIndex = CharCount - Len(Text) - 1                          ' Determines the character index of where the Text's characters begin
    EndIndex = CharCount - 1                                    ' Determines the character index of where the Text's characters end

    Set TextRng = ActiveDocument.Range(StartIndex, EndIndex)    ' Determines the range of characters that the text will occupy
    TextRng.Select
    With Selection
        With .Font
            .Size = FontSize                                    ' Sets the font size
            .Bold = Bold                                        ' Sets the boldness
            .Italic = Italics                                   ' Sets the italics
            If (Underline) Then                                 ' Sets the Underline
                .UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
                .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
            Else
                .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
            End If
        End With
    End With

    Select Case (Alignment)
        Case ("Center"):
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        Case ("Left"):
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        Case ("Right"):
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
        Case Else
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    End Select

    If LineReturn Then
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Text = String(LineReturn, Chr(13)) ' Adds any desired white space
    End If

End With

Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove ' Moves to the end of the document.

End Sub

Sub HeaderTest()

TextLineCreate "Message:", Underline:=True, LineReturn:=0
TextLineCreate " Hello World", Style:="Normal", Bold:=False, FontSize:=12, LineReturn:=1

End Sub
```

Updated Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnp0U.jpg

Comment: please post the pictures again with the paragraph marks showing

Comment: Okay, I updated it.

Comment: This question has been answered on another page now...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264715/vba-writing-to-word-changing-font-formatting?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nft                        ' Index to Array 'Formats'
    NftPara
    NftFont
    NftNew = 0
    NftAlign
    NftSpace
    NftFontSize
    NftBold
    NftItalic
    NftUnderline
End Enum

Private Sub Call_InsertText()
    ' 03 Dec 2017

    ' ============================================================

    '   'InsertText' requires 2 arguments as follows.
    '   The two arguments are separated from each other by a comma.
    '   1. 'Text' is the text to be inserted.
    '      It must be provided but can be a null string.
    '   2. 'Arg' is a string, consisting of two parts as follows.
    '      A) Paragraph formatting codes
    '      B) Font formatting codes
    '      Either or both can be omitted but if part B is present
    '      it MUST be preceded by a semicolon,
    '      even if part A is omitted.

    ' ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    '   Formatting Codes can be partially or entirely omitted,
    '   can be written in any sequence, upper or lower case,
    '   with or without spaces between them.
    '   If omitted, no setting will be applied, for example,
    '   if Bold isn't specified the inserted text will not be bold,
    '   if no space is specified, no space will be added,
    '   if no new line is specified the text will be added to the
    '   last existing line.

    ' ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    '   Paragraph formatting codes
    '   - N = New paragraph (the text will be inserted in a new line)
    '   - L = Left (Default: text will be aligned at the left margin)
    '   - R = Right (text will be aligned at the right margin)
    '   - C = Centre (text will be aligned at the centre)
    '   - 1 = A multiple of 12 pt added above or below a paragraph.
    '         Can be positive or negative and include decimal fractions.
    '         The default = 0
    '         For example, 2.5 adds 2 and a half lines to the space already
    '         specified for insertion below the indicated paragraph,
    '         -0.5 reduces the space by half a line.
    '         If the space to be reduced is larger than available below the
    '         indicated paragraph, the space will be added above it.

    '   Paragraph formatting rules
    '   If N (=New paragraph) is specified the formatting will be applied
    '   to the new paragraph. Otherwise the format will be applied to
    '   the last existing paragraph. L, R or C will over-write previously
    '   specified settings. Specified space is added to existing.

    '   Font formatting codes
    '   - B = Bold (the default is Not Bold)
    '   - I = Italics (the default is Not Italic)
    '   - U = Underlined (Single line. The default is no underline)
    '   - 9 = A number expressing the font size.
    '         The default size is determined by the "Normal" style.

    '   Font formatting rules
    '   Font formatting is applied the the currently specified text.
    '   Formatting applied to previously inserted texts can't be changed
    '   by this program.

    '   Exception "Title"
    '   The program will apply the "Title" style to the first line in a document,
    '   formatting both the paragraph and the font with that style.
    '   Any different formatting specified for that line will over-ride
    '   the style's settings.
    '   The program will insert a new, blank line following the title, ignoring
    '   the N (= New line) instruction if given for the next line. If spacing
    '   use the spacing functinality for the paragraph format.

    '   Notes
    '   This program doesn't specify a font, for example, which is presumed to be
    '   the font provided by the "Normal" style. The "Normal" style is applied to
    '   all new paragraphs this program inserts.

    ' ============================================================

    ' Run the code below to create a new document using the specified formatting

    InsertText "Document title", "C ;iu 27"
    InsertText "First line", "N1.8;8i"              ' N will be ignored
    InsertText "Second line", "N"
    InsertText "Add Bold Large", "1.5;24Bi"
    InsertText "Add Tiny", "-1;6u"
    InsertText "Another line", "N"
    InsertText "Another new line, right aligned, without space", "NR;b"
    InsertText "Add a left aligned line", "Nl;iu"
End Sub

Sub InsertText(ByVal Text As String, _
               Optional ByVal Arg As String)
    ' 03 Dec 2017
    ' insert the specified text, in the specified format,
    ' at the end of the ActiveDocument

    ' TextLineCreate Macro
    ' Creates a Formatted String with String 'Text'

    Dim Formats() As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Para As Paragraph
    Dim Tmp As Single

    If GetArguments(Arg, Formats) Then
        Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
        With Rng
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Set Para = .Paragraphs(1)
            If .End <= 1 Then
                ' the document is blank:-
                ' insert the Text as Title and insert a blank paragraph below it
                .InsertParagraphBefore
                Set Para = .Paragraphs(1)
                Para.Style = "Title"
                .Collapse wdCollapseStart
            Else
                ' the 2nd para was inserted by the program together with the title
                If (ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count = 2) And _
                   (Len(Para.Range.Text) < 2) Then Formats(NftNew) = False
                If Formats(NftNew) = vbTrue Then
                    .InsertParagraphAfter
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    Set Para = .Paragraphs(1)
                    Para.Style = wdStyleNormal
                End If
            End If

            ' add a space between components
            If (Len(Para.Range.Text) > 1) And _
               (Right(Para.Range.Text, 1) <> " ") And _
               (Asc(Text) <> 32) Then
               .InsertBefore " "
               .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            End If
            .Text = Text

            With .Font                          ' format the Font
                If Formats(NftFontSize) <> wdUndefined Then
                    If .Size <> Formats(NftFontSize) Then .Size = Formats(NftFontSize)
                End If
                If Formats(NftBold) <> wdUndefined Then
                    If .Bold <> Formats(NftBold) Then .Bold = Formats(NftBold)
                End If
                If Formats(NftItalic) <> wdUndefined Then
                    If .Italic <> Formats(NftItalic) Then .Italic = Formats(NftItalic)
                End If
                If Formats(NftUnderline) <> wdUndefined Then
                    .UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
                End If
            End With
        End With

        With Para                          ' format the paragraph
            If Formats(NftAlign) <> wdUndefined Then
                If .Alignment <> Formats(NftAlign) Then .Alignment = Formats(NftAlign)
            End If
            If Formats(NftSpace) <> wdUndefined Then
                Tmp = .SpaceAfter + Formats(NftSpace)
                If Tmp < 0 Then
                    .SpaceAfter = 0
                    .SpaceBefore = Abs(Tmp)
                Else
                    .SpaceAfter = Tmp
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetArguments(ByVal Arg As String, _
                              Formats() As Variant) As Boolean
    ' 03 Dec 2017
    ' assign parameter values to Formats()
    ' return False if fault was found in Arg

    Dim Fun As Boolean                      ' function return value
    Dim Sp() As String                      ' split of Arg
    Dim Fmt() As Variant                    ' split of Sp
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    ReDim Formats(NftUnderline)
    For i = LBound(Formats) To UBound(Formats)
        Formats(i) = wdUndefined
    Next i

    Arg = UCase(Replace(Arg, " ", ""))
    If Len(Arg) Then
        Sp = Split(Arg, ";")
    End If

    Fun = Not ((Not Sp) = -1)               ' not empty array
    If Fun Then
        ReDim Fmt(NftFont)
        For i = NftPara To NftFont
            If i <= UBound(Sp) Then
                Fmt(i) = SplitArg(Sp(i))
                n = 0
                Do While Len(Fmt(i)(n))
                    If IsNumeric(Fmt(i)(n)) Then
                        If i = NftPara Then
                            Formats(NftSpace) = Int(Val(Fmt(i)(n)) * 12)
                        Else
                            Formats(NftFontSize) = Val(Fmt(i)(n))
                        End If
                    Else
                        Select Case Fmt(i)(n)
                            Case "N"
                                Formats(NftNew) = vbTrue
                            Case "L", "C", "R"
                                Formats(NftAlign) = InStr("LCR", Fmt(i)(n)) - 1
                            Case "B"
                                Formats(NftBold) = vbTrue
                            Case "I"
                                Formats(NftItalic) = vbTrue
                            Case "U"
                                Formats(NftUnderline) = vbTrue
                            Case Else
                                MsgBox "The formatting argument """ & Fmt(i)(n) & _
                                       """ isn't recognised." & vbCr & _
                                       "Please review the instruction.", _
                                       vbInformation, "Invalid formatting code"
                                Fun = False
                                Exit Do
                        End Select
                    End If
                    n = n + 1
                    If n > UBound(Fmt(i)) Then Exit Do
                Loop
            End If
            If Not Fun Then Exit For
        Next i
    End If

    GetArguments = Fun
End Function

Private Function SplitArg(ByVal Arg As String) As Variant
    ' 03 Dec 2017

    Dim Fun() As String
    Dim Ch As String
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

    ReDim Fun(Len(Arg))
    For i = 1 To Len(Arg)
        Ch = Mid(Arg, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Ch) Or (InStr(".-", Ch) > 0) Then
            If Len(Fun(n)) Then
                If (Not IsNumeric(Fun(n))) And (Fun(n) <> ".") And _
                   (Fun(n) <> "-") And (Fun(n) <> "-.") Then n = n + 1
                End If
            Fun(n) = Fun(n) & Ch
        Else
            If Len(Fun(n)) Then n = n + 1
            Fun(n) = Ch
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve Fun(n)
    SplitArg = Fun
End Function
```

Comment: This works, but it types all of my text backwards
https://imgur.com/a/ehdVW

Comment: Okay, so I fixed that, but if you look at what I added today, it still does wierd formatting stuff when I run the program a second time.

Comment: Oops! That was a leftover from testing. Please replace the line `If StrComp(Align(i), "right", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ` with `If StrComp(Align(i), Alignment, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then `.

Comment: This still prints everything backwards, you'll notice I supplied a test subroutine with the new sample code I gave you that creates a standard message, "Message: Hello World" with the 'Message:' portion bolded and underlined, and the 'Hello World' portion is not.  This code needs to be executed programmatically and cannot be dependent on my selecting things in the file by hand

Comment: Yes, I also think that it is my lack of knowledge of your workflow and the environment in which the code is supposed to work that prevents me from helping you better. How do you call the sub we are talking about? How do you enter the parameters? How do you specify the location of each text?

Comment: I am executing the macro from a vi in LabVIEW, twice, once for the bolded title, and then once, for the normal text parameter.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. You should have a template with the title already bold and marked by a bookmark. Then the code would create a document from the template and replace the bookmarked title with the one from your vi. Same for all other values. In your approach the right-alignment you complain about is in the template, not in the code. You should make this feature work for you instead of fighting it, meaning you must look at the template, not the code.

Comment: I can't use the template to my advantage because certain features don't show up in each report, the code needs to be template agnostic, it needs to be able to work so that once I write it, my manager won't have to touch it again if he adds sections to the report generation.

Comment: Before you can insert anything into a document you must know where to insert it. For this purpose, my sub looks at the current `Selection`. You said that the program can't depend on any selection. In which way might the program then know at which point to insert the words or paragraphs the code should insert?

Comment: Assume that it's a new document being created every time, so the cursor will always be at the very beginning of the document to start with. (Or, at the very end, since there's nothing in it yet, either) Then for the rest of the program, it's to assume that the cursor is always at the very end of the document.

Comment: Do you need the ability to add text to an existing line? Or is it correct to say that every time the macro is called a new line will be added (except for the very first line in a new document)?

Comment: It needs to be able to add text to an existing line

Comment: The revised code above tries to simplify command entry. Let me know if it doesn't fit into the way you prefer or need to work.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, thank you so much for your help, I'm sorry if I was a pain.  I tried to upvote this, but I can't cuz I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Glad it helped you! You may not have the authority to up-vote but you do have the authority to select the answer which answered your question. Please do so. It helps others, too.